# Does Apache log each request?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, logging

How to tell Apache to log each request (visit)??
I'm looking for a bug in my code, and I have to track visitor.

Comment: It already does, by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Apache does log quite a bit into `/var/log/apache2`, and also records every http request. If you have code going wrong, the tasty details may be in the error log hosted in that directory.

Comment: This post was tagged [tag:centos] and in CentOS the logs are in `/var/log/httpd` by default.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I spend time bipping between several distros, so not surprised I got it wrong.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 - To be fair, he tagged it with both CentOS AND Apache. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly basic and also fairly vague, but I'm going to go ahead and take a stab at answering it anyway.

The short answer is yes, Apache can (but doesn't always) log requests. Apache can log several things. Normally error logs and access logs are logged to separate files. On one of my CentOS servers, I log errors to /var/log/httpd/error_log (and sometimes individual vhosts' error logs are logged to yet a different file location).

Access logs and Error logs are defined typically in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (CentOS / Red Hat) and /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

However, vhosts will sometimes be configured to log errors and/or access logs to override the default setting.

Good luck.